# Netsuite field doesn't show on kit record

Tags: customization, netsuite

There is a field called 'IsDropShipItem' that we're trying to show on an Assembly/Group Item Form. When customizing the form, we can see it under Fields -> Inventory and it is marked to Show, but it doesn't show up on the record. It shows fine on the Inventory Item forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that Kit items in NetSuite cannot be drop shipped. They are technically not an inventoried item, they are only a collection of their components, and as such, they cannot be purchased from a vendor. Group items will have the same issue. I recommend recreating your Kit item as an Assembly item, then you will be able to see and check the `isDropShipItem` checkbox.